# Return e(edge) in traversal in ArangoDB

Tags: traversal, arangodb, aql

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..2 INBOUND 'company_nodes_2018_2023/6066a658fee3c9fc8c1c84b7' 
GRAPH supply_chain_graph
OPTIONS { uniqueVertices: 'path', maxIterations: 100000}
FILTER p.edges[0].hs_codes == 820559 AND p.edges[1].hs_codes == 950300 AND p.edges[*].actual_arrival_date ALL >= '2018-01' AND p.edges[*].actual_arrival_date ALL <= '2023-02' 
LIMIT 500000
RETURN e
```

In the above query it is returning only one edge that is of 1st level which has hs_codes == 950300.
Edge of level 0 containing 820559 is not shown .
Can anyone please tell me why.

Comment: Return 'p' and see if that helps you work it out. Also comment out your date limits to make sure there are more to return.

Comment: Hello David , Returning p wont work because i was using return e for unique edges.

Comment: Do you want to return all edges of a path or not? In general, a variable depth traversal may match different lengths of the same path, but I guess you are only interested in the longest one? You may have to post-filter the results on the client-side for this. Or, depending on your use case, wrap the query in a subquery and only return every edge once. This won't preserve any order, however. BTW. Since you have conditions for the edges at depth 1 and 2, I think you should change the traversal depth to 2..2, and there is no `maxIterations` option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is by definition:

> edge (object, optional): the current edge in a traversal

Means e is changing based on the depth of the current iteration (that why you are seen only the last one).

Instead of returning the `e`, if you want both of the edges you should return p.edge[0] and p.edge[1].